# Remove records based on priority in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

details table

```
name age sports
john 27  football
john 27  cricket 
john 27  basketball
kyle 28  baseball
kyle 28  football
nick 24  football
nick 24  hockey
ron  35  football
```

Priority table :

```
name       priority
futsal     1
basketball 2
football   3
cricket    4
baseball   5
hockey     6

desired table :    

name age sports 
john 27  basketball  --as basketball has the highest priority for john
kyle 28  baseball
nick 24  football
ron  35  football
```

What is desired is that i want to keep only 1 record for a name and rest should be deleted based on priority of sports .
I know to delete duplicate records but can anyone suggest me can this be accomplished in sql server and
how!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the join use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select d.name, d.age, d.sports,
             row_number() over (partition by d.name order by p.priority) as seq
      from details d inner join
           priority p
           on p.name = d.sports
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: this will not work , basically you are joining with priority tables and removing the duplicates. What i want is that only those record should come up having the highest priority

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  Here is one method:

```
select dp.*
from (select d.*, min(p.priority) over (partition by d.name)
      from details d join
           priorities p
           on d.sport = p.name
     ) dp
where seqnum = 1;
```